# Is there an infinite sequence of complex numbers $a_1, a_2, a_3, \ldots$ such that $a_1^m + a_2^m + a_3^m + \ldots = m$ for every positive integer m?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-numbers, puzzle

A similar question was asked for the case where all $a_i$ are real here: [Is there an infinite sequence of real numbers $a_1, a_2, a_3,... $ such that ${a_1}^m+{a_2}^m+a_3^m+...=m$ for every positive integer $m$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1798994/is-there-an-infinite-sequence-of-real-numbers-a-1-a-2-a-3-such-that-a)

Comment: there is a comment under the accepted answer giving a sketch of applying the argument to the complexes

Comment: @WillJagy Yeah, I saw that comment, but the argument seems false in the case where there are multiple complex numbers with the same (maximal) magnitude

Comment: I think there is a lot of detail hidden in the comment "their sum [the multiple complex numbers with same max magnitude] acts exponentially for some [sub]sequence of n".  I.e. their "angles" align frequently enough to have a subsequence grow exponential.  I personally don't know how to show that.

Comment: @antkam Yes, that is probably the case, but would seem to require some number theoretic machinery to show

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was problem $B$-$1$ on the Putnam exam in $2010$. You can find the detailed solution [here](https://kskedlaya.org/putnam-archive/2010s.pdf). In essence, the answer is that there is no such sequence of $a_i$ exists if we assme that the series $\sum a_i^m$ converges absolutely, and the solution manual provides a proof. It also provides a construction of a particular series of $a_n$ which satisfy the conditions, despite $\sum a_i^m$ not being absolutely convergent.

> **Third solution.**
>   We generalize the second solution to show that for any positive integer $k$, it is impossible for a sequence
>   $a_1, a_2,\dots$ of complex numbers to satisfy the given conditions in case
>   the series $a_1^k + a_2^k + \cdots$ converges absolutely. This includes the original problem by taking
>   $k=2$, in which case the series $a_1^2 + a_2^2 + \cdots$ consists of nonnegative
>   real numbers and so converges absolutely if it converges at all.
>
> Since the sum $\sum_{i=1}^\infty |a_i|^k$ converges by hypothesis, we can find a positive integer $n$
>   such that $\sum_{i=n+1}^\infty |a_i|^k < 1$. For each positive integer $d$, we then have
>   $$
> \left|kd - \sum_{i=1}^n a_i^{kd} \right|
> \leq \sum_{i=n+1}^\infty |a_i|^{kd} < 1.
> $$
>   We thus cannot have $|a_1|,\dots,|a_n| \leq 1$, or else the sum $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^{kd}$ would be bounded
>   in absolute value by $n$ independently of $d$. But if we put $r = \max\{|a_1|,\dots,|a_n|\} > 1$, we
>   obtain another contradiction because for any $\epsilon > 0$,
>   $$
> \limsup_{d \to \infty} (r-\epsilon)^{-kd} \left| \sum_{i=1}^n a_i^{kd} \right| > 0.
> $$
>   For instance, this follows from applying the root test to the rational function
>   $$
> \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{1 - a_i^k z} = \sum_{d=0}^\infty \left( \sum_{i=1}^n a_i^{kd} \right) z^d,
> $$
>   which has a pole within the circle $|z| \leq r^{-1/k}$.
>   (An elementary proof is also possible.)

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $(a_k)$ is a sequence of complex numbers such that

- $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k^m$ converges for each $m$, and
- there exists $m_0 \geq 1$ such that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} |a_k|^{m_0} < \infty$.

Then it is impossible to have $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k^m = m$ for all $m \geq 1$ (or even for all sufficiently large $m$). To this end, we assume otherwise and show that this leads to a contradiction.

Let $R = (\sup_{k\geq 1} |a_k|)^{-1} $. Then for any $|z| < R$,

$$ \frac{z}{(1-z)^2} - \Biggl( \sum_{m=1}^{m_0 - 1} m z^m \Biggr) = \sum_{m=m_0}^{\infty} m z^m = \sum_{m=m_0}^{\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k^m z^m = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(a_k z)^{m_0}}{1 - a_k z}. $$

In the second step, we utilized the Fubini's theorem. The right-hand side converges locally uniformly on any compact subset of $\mathbb{C} \setminus A$ with $A = \{a_k^{-1} : k \geq 1 \text{ and } a_k \neq 0 \}$. Then for any bounded, simply connected region $\mathcal{D}$ such that $1 \in \mathcal{D}$ and $\partial\mathcal{D}$ avoids $A$,

\begin{align*}
1
= \frac{i}{2\pi} \int_{\partial\mathcal{D}} \Biggl( \sum_{m=m_0}^{\infty} m z^m \Biggr) \, \mathrm{d}z
= \frac{i}{2\pi}  \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \int_{\partial\mathcal{D}}  \frac{(a_k z)^{m_0}}{1 - a_k z} \, \mathrm{d}z
= \sum_{k \, : \, a_k^{-1} \in \mathcal{D}} \frac{1}{a_k}.
\end{align*}

Since $A$ is discrete, this implies that $A \subseteq \{1\}$ and there is exactly one non-zero element in $(a_k)$, which takes value $1$. Then it is obvious that such sequence cannot satisfy $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k^m = m$ for large $m$. $\square$

Without absolute convergence condition, I even have no idea whether the statement is true or not.