# Does there exists a sequence of real numbers $(a_n)$ such that $a_1^n + a_2^n + a_3^n + \cdots = n$ for every positive integer $n$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

Does there exists a sequence of real numbers $(a_n)$ such that

$$a_1^n + a_2^n + a_3^n + \cdots = n$$ for every positive integer $n$.

---

I tried the following:

Suppose such a sequence exists, then we have $$a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + \cdots =1$$

$$a_1^2 + a_2^2+a_3^2 + \cdots = 2$$

Thus we have $$a_1^2 + a_2^2+a_3^2 + \cdots = 2(a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + \cdots)$$

I am stuck with it. Any hint is appreciable. Thanks.

---

Homework question.

Comment: And for complex numbers: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3391498/42969

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There cannot exist such a sequence. Suppose such a sequence $(a_n)$ did exist. Then by  the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality $$10= \sum^\infty_{n=1} a_n^{10} = \sum^\infty_{n=1} a_n^2a_n^8 \le \sqrt{\sum^\infty_{n=1} a_n^4}\, \cdot \sqrt{\sum^\infty_{n=1} a^{16}_{n}} = \sqrt 4 \, \cdot \sqrt{16} = 8.$$

EDIT: for a more "elementary" argument, not requiring the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, suppose such a sequence $(a_n)$ did exist. If $\lvert a_n\rvert > 1$ for any $n \in \mathbb N$, then for sufficiently large $m \in \mathbb N$, we must have $a_n^{2m} > 2m$, since $a_n^{2m}$ grows exponentially in $m$, while $2m$ grows linearly in $m$. But this would contradict $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a^{2m}_n = 2m$. Thus we must have $\lvert a_n \rvert \le 1$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$. However, in that case $a_n^4 \le a_n^2$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$, so $4 = \sum^\infty_{n=1} a^4_n \le \sum^\infty_{n=1} a_n^2 = 2$, a contradiction.